# Casper --proxy doesn't work

Tags: node.js, proxy, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Here is my code to check for IP address using http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check

```js
var casper = require("casper").create(),
    utils = require('utils');

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');

casper.start("http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check", function() {
  this.capture('0.png');
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('Remote: ' + msg);
})

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo('End');

  //finish execution script 
  this.exit();  

});
```

I typed `casperjs --proxy="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80" proxy.js`
But the screenshot is exactly the IP address from my machine.

So how do I know if the proxy is bad or if something wrong in my code or command line?

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine for me, I got a different screenshot when I used proxy.
Does  the proxy  require authentication?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to test if casperjs is successfully using the proxy server, you can use the following script test. It makes a request to [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/) and print the IP address used by casperjs.

```js
//create casper object
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://www.whatismyip.com/');

//to avoid 'Access Denied'  <!-- Error #1010 -->
//The owner of this website (www.whatismyip.com) has banned  
//your access based on your browser's signature (42c0a6c6-cl-ua-50). (Ref. 1010)
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');

//Home Page
casper.then(function() {

    if(this.exists('div#greenip')){

        var element = this.evaluate(function() {
            //remove unnecessari nodes
            return jQuery('div#greenip').text().trim();
        });

        console.log(element);   
    }else{
        console.log("ACCESS_DENIED");   
    }    

});

casper.run(function() {

    //finish execution script 
    this.exit();
});
```

The output:

> casperjs --proxy=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:60099 --proxy-auth=username:password proxy.js 
>  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Comment: As of Jan 2014, the #greenip element doesn't exist

Comment: Feb 2015, replace `#greenip` with `#ip-box > div.ip-box-left > div.the-ip`

Answer (score 4):

A shorter casperjs script using http://ip-addr.es/

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'http://ip-addr.es/';

casper.start(url, function() {
    var js = this.evaluate(function() {
        return document; 
    }); 
    this.echo(js.all[0].outerText); 
});
casper.run();
```

Assuming you have saved the previous script as whatismyip.js, and you have a SOCKSv5 proxy listening on localhost port 8000, then you can check if casperjs is currently using a proxy as:

```
simone@tramontana:~$ casperjs  whatismyip.js 
93.[xx].[xx].226 # I've hidden a couple of bytes of my real IP ;)

simone@tramontana:~$ casperjs --proxy=127.0.0.1:8000 --proxy-type=socks5 whatismyip.js 
46.23.73.4
```

Comment: Please don't return non-primitive objects from the page context (`evaluate()`). This is highly error prone in PhantomJS. `js.all` is probably empty.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and it works fine for me

Running the script without proxy.

> casperjs proxy.js

[image: img1]

Running the script with proxy.

> casperjs --proxy=208.72.118.16:60099 --proxy-auth=username:password  proxy.js

[image: img2]

Comment: Does that mean my command line is wrong with the quotation marks? Because there is no auth. I got some samples from here http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/

Comment: the quotation marks should not affect the command. I guess the problems is the proxy that you are using.

Comment: I have tried to run your code using a free proxy of hidemyass.com  Example : [casperjs  --proxy=152.1.150.52:8080  proxy.js] some proxies work, but others don't.

Comment: So how do we know if a proxy don't work? Because casperjs basically use the current machine's IP

Comment: casperjs uses you current machine's IP by default if you don't specified a proxy, In order to be sure if casperjs is using a proxy for each request, you could create a script test to get the ip from    http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: I tried both `casperjs --proxy=152.1.150.52:8080 proxy.js` and `casperjs --proxy=208.72.118.16:60099 proxy.js` but still cannot see different IP than my local machine from the screenshot `0.png`. Am I missing something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30937/discussion-between-hemerson-varela-and-hp)